# Количество операций превышает 4 месяца

Tags: sql, oracle

Нужно написать запрос oracle sql, который позволит вывести диапазон между датами операций

Comment: Ну ладно DDL нет и хоть каких-то попыток решения. Вы бы хоть указали, между какими именно операциями должно быть 4 месяца.

Comment: 4 месяца должно быть между любыми операциями по одному человеку.

Comment: Т.е. Вы хотите вывести людей, у которых в логе транзакций есть окна шириной не менее 4 мес.? Верно?

Comment: Для более-менее адекватного запроса не хватает идентификаторов пользователя/транзакции

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы отсеять диапазоны операции их надо как-то получить. Можно воспользоваться соединением таблицы с самой собой `from youtable join yourtable b`. Так как вы указали, что операции по одному человеку, то условие соединения `on a."ФИО" = b."ФИО"`. Вообще, так делать нельзя, вместо ФИО для соединения должен использоваться уникальный код клиента или лицевого счета, но его не видно на вашем скриншоте.

Теперь у нас есть выборка, которая перебирает все возможные пары операций по одному ФИО. Чтобы выполнить ваше условие про 4 месяца, можно воспользоваться функцией `MONTHS_BETWEEN`. Но ознакомьтесь с тем как именно она высчитывает разницу в месяцах, удовлетворит это ваши требования или нет. Дело в том что, есть несколько логических парадоксов когда, диапазоны времени пытаются измерить в единицах не имеющих фиксированной длины (год, месяц).

Последний штрих в данный запрос. Т.к. операций проходящих условию могло быть много, а надо вывести только ФИО, то следует добавить ключевое слово `DISTINCT`. Оно позволит убрать повторы ФИО в выборке.

```
select distinct a."ФИО"
from yourtable a
join yourtable b
  on a."ФИО" = b."ФИО"
where
  months_between (a."ДАТА_ОПЕРАЦИИ", b."ДАТА_ОПЕРАЦИИ") > 4
```

Comment: Хороший ответ на плохой вопрос.